# How to compile libxml2 and libcurl to 32-bit under 64-bit machine?

Tags: c, linux, installation, libcurl, libxml2

I download the packages libxml2-2.9.1.tar.gz and curl-7.31.0.tar.gz from thw web. If I compile these two under 32-bit machine, it'll be ok. But formal environment is 64-bit machine, after I compiled thest two, libxml2 and libcurl became 64-bit. When I ran the application program, it reported an error. 
  Now, how can I compile these two packages into 32-bit, under a 64-bit machine? I found on the 64-bit machine, there is an old package libxml2.so.2.6.26 in /usr/local/lib, it is 64-bit file; but in /usr/lib, there also has a file libxml2.so.2.6.16, it is 32-bit. It really confuses me a lot.

I just hope the application program can run ok, Someone help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `CFLAGS='-m32' ./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Just input CFLAGS='-m32' in the shell? then run ./configure etc.

Comment: @lalalalalalalala The first part of the command is `CFLAGS='-m32' ./configure`. Literally. Like this. Nothing else.

Comment: I input the command CFLAGS='-m32', then ./configure .. ;but the result is 64-bit.libxml2.so.2.9.1 is 4236595byte. If it's 32bit, it is just a half. Could you please say it more clearly?

Comment: @lalalalalala And you? Could **you** be clearer? What's all with the code sizes? It won't drop magically to half the size if you compile for 32 bit, that's not how machine word size works. And say *what* more clearly? I'm getting tired. You hammer the command in the terminal, hit `Enter` and wait until the compiler does its job.

Comment: The steps I've done is below:
1.in the bash shell, i input CFLAGS='-m32'   2. ./configure   3.make   4.make install

Comment: on the 32-bit machine , after I install the package , libxml2.so.2.9.1 is 2395903byte, but on the 64-bit machine, it gets to 4236595byte. So It must be sth. wrong with me. I just want to solve this problem.No other means.

Comment: lalala learn to use shell. He said very clearly the command is `CFLAGS='-m32' ./configure`. Got it? No new line!

Comment: I just got an error:  error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an environment variable so that configure sees it. The proper command is like H2CO3 said:

```
CFLAGS='-m32' ./configure
```

**NOT like this**

```
CFLAGS='-m32'
./configure
```

These are not the same command, the latter sets up a variable in the shell; **no command will see the value of `CFLAGS`**, whereas the former sets the `CFLAGS` in an environment that will be passed to the `execve` for running the `./configure` command.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake for me. I input these commands in the bash shell: CFLAGS='-m32' ./configure   make   ;then, it told me an error: error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?). Can you tell me the reason? thank you.

Comment: I would first remove the old source directory, and redo. Or then your system does not have 32-bit development libraries.

Comment: On ubuntu the following should be enough `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`